# SFINAE expression fails to compile with clang

Tags: gcc, clang, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

This looks like an issue in clang (I've already opened a bug [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27970)), but I'd like to be sure that I'm not doing a mistake.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M, std::enable_if_t<not (N>M)>* = nullptr> // (1)
struct S: public S<N+1, M> { };

template<std::size_t N>
struct S<N, N> { };

int main() {
    S<0, 1> c{};
}
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

> 8 : error: non-type template argument specializes a template parameter with dependent type 'std::enable_if_t M)> *' (aka 'typename enable_if M), void>::type *')
>   struct S { };

The same code works as expected using the following line instead of (1):

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M, typename = std::enable_if_t<not (N>M)>>
```

The SFINAE expression is almost the same. It is based on a specialization of `std::enable_if_t` and I would expect the same result (success or failure) for both of the examples.
Are my expectations wrong?

Note that GCC works fine in either cases.

Comment: The whole thing seems to be non-working to me. The parameter type in the primary template is always going to be constructed, regardless of whether it or the specialization is selected. So the enable_if will always fail and the `main` method will be ill-formed.

Comment: The relevant text is "In a type name that refers to a class template specialization, (e.g., A<int, int, 1>) the argument list shall match the template parameter list of the primary template. The template arguments of a specialization are deduced from the arguments of the primary template.". The "arguments of the primary template" is the implicit argument list that conceptually follows the unspecialized case: `struct S<N,M,<unnamed>>`. And in your case, the unnamed argument got an invalid type, which will result in ill-formed code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The whole thing works as expected with GCC (even though it shouldn't, but the sfinae expression is valid). It still works if you change it in `typename = std::enable_if<...`, this time both with GCC and clang. As an example, `S<0, 2>` is accepted, while `S<2, 0>` is not. The `enable_if` won't fail in the first case, but it will in the second. I don't get your point, I'm sorry.

Comment: my point is that your parameter type is not an SFINAE context. You have probably seen `enable_if` expressions in partial specializations, where they are in SFINAE contexts, but as a type in a primary template they are not SFINAE contexts. And placing it as a default argument probably does something else than what you think it does: You possibly expected this to compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/486ba2517bf67c18

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb No, I wouldn't expect it to compile for `N` (that is 2) is greater than `M` (that is 1) and the template class' `enable_if` has `not (N>M)` as an expression. I would expect it to compile with `S<1, 2>` and [it actually works as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3eb0888fb682e53). The sfinae expression mainly serves the purpose of avoiding inheritance chains that won't finish. I still don't understand what's wrong with it...

Comment: what I'm saying is that it's not an sfinae expression. It's just a "substitution failure *is* an error" expression. If N>M in `S<N,M>`, your code is always ill-formed. There is no "not an error" part of SFINAE in there.  The term SFINAE is used for cases where substitution fails, but where it is *not* an error and an alternative declaration can be considered (`S<2, 1>` in my example).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Oh, no, now I got what you mean!! You are right. That's not sfinae at all. Anyway, it doesn't change the fact that GCC should not accept it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a gcc bug actually, as a result of [temp.class.spec]:

> The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized
>   non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the
>   specialization. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T, T t> struct C {};
> template <class T> struct C<T, 1>;       // error
>
> template< int X, int (*array_ptr)[X] > class A {};
> int array[5];
> template< int X > class A<X,&array> { }; // error
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

In your example, the type of the 3rd template parameter is dependent on a parameter. When you swap it to `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>`, then this rule no longer applies.

---

Note: is there any reason to use SFINAE here anyway, as opposed to `static_assert`-ing?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get the fact that swapping _(1)_ changes the rules and the sfinae expression is no longer a parameter. Actually it makes sense. Reasons to use sfinae instead of a static assert? Uhm... not exactly, I'm more biased towards sfinae expressions for they are the firsts to come up to my mind, but here a static assert would be fine as well, absolutely.

Comment: I'm opening a bug to GCC meanwhile and closing the one to clang. Thank you for the citation from the standard. I'll link your answer as a reference

Comment: @T.C. Is there a resolution to that?